# Javascript generete table in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am getting data from Database trought PHP to my jQuery function `$.getJSON` which generetes table in html. This function creates a variable called innerHTML which is a simple string. I simply run some loops and concatenate this variable with new data and tags `<table><thead><tbody><tr><td>` etc. At the end I just run `document.getElementByID('myTable').innerHTML = innerHTML;`

My questions are:

1. Would it be better to generate my innerHTML with an array?
2. What happens if the user won't have enough memory to concatenate the string?
3. Can I create an array which will get bigger the larger my table is and then convert it to string? 
   Or maybe should I concatenate the actuall innerHTML of my element on the site?

I find this method of generating the table very simple and self explaining, that's why I use it. But I really don't know if this may become a memory issue when data gets larger - This works fine now - but what could happen in the future?

**UPDATE**

I used another way to do the trick. In the loops insted of extending string or array I use appendChild, creating all elements of the table that I need.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use Array or String. Both are going to take the same memory if the data amount is same. Try to add lazy loading or pagination in your app to handle such scenes. Don't load the whole data at once in innerHTML object. Also if you want to Try Array Manipulations then you should try Mori.js or Immutable.js which reduce the memory usage for the copies of the same data for processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When data gets really large, you might think about only adding some rows at a time and then append more rows when the network is free, or the user demands it.

In terms of speed, i think you chose the fastest way possible to dynamically change the content of your DOM (in comparison to using jQuery for that and not concatenating your whole data), BUT when data gets large, it's pretty likely for your application to get stuck on readability when using your custom way.